# How do I present the Mac color picker (eye dropper) in Chrome on Mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, firefox

In the Bio Daliance web app http://www.biodalliance.org the user can - on a Mac using Chrome/Firefox - present what looks like the Mac system color picker. Seen here on the right. Does anyone what JS code is used to make this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with pure HTML, using the `color` input type:

```
<input type="color">
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color).